# Как реализовать данный элемент в android?

Tags: java, android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаю, как называется данный элемент, поэтому прикрепляю картинку.
Может, уже есть готовые библиотеки?

Comment: Ну так напишите его сами! Есть либа `DiscreteSeekBar`, можете ее модифицировать :)

Comment: @Flippy 
 
Здравствуйте,остался вопрос, как сделать цифры как на элементе который я скинул? Я отредактировал визуально все, и у меня получилось. Осталось реализовать цифры внутри SnackBar , как это сделать?

Comment: Вы модифицировали либу? Или что вы сделали?

Comment: @Flippy сам сделал, задал новый вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/646779/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-seekbar-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80%d1%8b/646787#646787

Comment: Вам нужен кастомный `SeekBar`, то что вы сделали можете стереть

Comment: @Flippy , и с чего мне начать?Дайте направление

Comment: Создайте класс, унаследуйте его от `SeekBar` и вперед

Comment: @Flippy так и сделал, но пробелемы  с дальнешими действиями, я встал на переопределении метода onDraw

Comment: Изучайте `View`, сам `SeekBar`. Помочь я не могу, лень :) Кстати, вы учли, что то что вам нужно выходит за границы? То что вы сделали является ползунком который едет от 0 до 100 умещаясь на ширине. Выходит цифры рисовать негде. Извините, если показал вам не ту сторону куда копать. Возможно вам нужен `RecyclerView` (список) горизонтально "катающийся". Впринципе это легко, создать разметку с черточками, и `TextView` в центре. В адаптере в `getItemCount` возвращать 200 а в `TexrView` биндить `позиция / 2f`. Насчет розового квадрата. Когда он должен появляться? При клике? Он может кататься?

Comment: Если при клике, то вполне можно реализовать с помощью `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @Flippy да, он может кататься. 
Если буду создавать RecyclerView, то что как мой элемент будет выглядеть?
Я немного запутался.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56426/discussion-between-flippy-and--).

Answer (score 2):

Это называется [SeekBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html)

Посмотрите [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13797807/android-how-to-add-intervals-texts-in-a-seekbar), там рассматривается задача отдаленно схожая с вашей.

Также можете погуглить выражение `Android Linear Gauge`.

Comment: Здравствуйте,остался вопрос, как сделать цифры как на элементе который я скинул?

Я отредактировал визуально все, и у меня получилось.
Осталось реализовать цифры внутри SnackBar , как это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуй начинаю писать `LineageView` :)

Вот код, в котором будет лента-список. При нажатии на айтем он красится в красный.

**LineageAdapter**

```
public class LineageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LineageAdapter.AdapterHolder>
{
int choicePosition;

public class AdapterHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        int pos = getAdapterPosition();
        notifyItemChanged(choicePosition);
        choicePosition = pos;
        notifyItemChanged(choicePosition);
    }

    TextView number;

    AdapterHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        number = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.number);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    void bind(int position)
    {
        float value = (position + 1) / 2f;
        String str = Float.toString(value);
        number.setText(str);

        if (position == choicePosition)
        {
            //itemView.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        else
        {
            //itemView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
    }
}

LineageAdapter()
{
    choicePosition = -1;
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
{
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

@Override
public AdapterHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int p2)
{
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.lineage_item, viewGroup, false);
    AdapterHolder pvh = new AdapterHolder(v);
    return pvh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AdapterHolder holder, int position)
{
    holder.bind(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount()
{
    return 200;
}
}
```

**lineage_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**LineageActivity**

```
public class LineageActivity extends Activity 
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lineage_sample);
    RecyclerView lineage = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.lineage);
    LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
    lineage.setLayoutManager(manager);
    LineageAdapter adapter = new LineageAdapter();
    lineage.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

**lineage_sample**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/lineage"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Скрин**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]