# Как в Seekbar вставить цифры?

Tags: java, android, ui

Здравствуйте,как сделать цифры как на элементе который я скинул? Я отредактировал визуально все, и у меня получилось. Осталось реализовать цифры внутри SnackBar , как это сделать?

[image: Что нужно:]

Что сделано:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос как вставить цифры?

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <size android:height="50dp" android:width="50dp" />

        <gradient
            android:angle="45"
            android:endColor="#4e84ff"
            android:startColor="#4e84ff" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <clip>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="45dp" />

            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:endColor="#4e84ff"
                android:startColor="#4e84ff" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
```

```
<SeekBar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:progress="0"

    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:max="100"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо было показать код, было бы проще сказать что-то конкретное, а так неясно, как вы это сделали и что где добавить.
В целом, логика такая, что нужно "перехватить" (`Override`) какой-то метод базового класса, управляющий отрисовкой элементов `SeekBar`, и с помощью Graphics реализовать рисование текста и черточек, точнее, черточки можно просто включить в background drawable, а вот текст - рисовать.

Comment: Добавил код в вопросе

Comment: Какой-то метод - это какой?
И как реализовать рисование?