# Как скроллить RecyclerView и изменять ползунок

Tags: java, android

У меня есть горизонтальный ListView состоящий из RelativeLayout,который включает в себя один элемент - TextView.

При скролле влево ползунок красного цвета, должен сдавигаться вправо, когда он останавливается на 1 элементе страницы, то он соответственно не должен пропасть, а должен находится на 1 элементе страницы.Как это реализовать?

Comment: Штатный экстрасенс в отпуске, без кода не помочь

Comment: @zTrap добавил код

Comment: @zTrap куда же вы пропали?)

Comment: Описание проблемы совершенно не понятно. Как здесь [задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить полезный ответ.

Comment: ListView или все-таки RecyclerView? Scrollbar должен всегда быть виден, а не исчезать при остановке прокрутки, верно понял? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702502/how-to-always-show-scrollbar

Comment: Я так понял вам нужен ползунок который будет всегда стоять в середине `ListView`? Вы можете сделать чтобы на экране всегда отображалось например 5 айтемов ленты. А закрашивать красным всегда 3 айтем. Или вам нужно закрашивать всегда первый? Тогда как должно быть при прокрутке вправо до упора?

Comment: @Rou1997, автор имеет ввиду не то. Посмотрите на мой ответ - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/645724/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b2-android?noredirect=1#comment923632_645724